# In Elasticsearch match query how to deal with slash

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, mapping, match

I have a match query searching for a type of doc:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "match": {
          "ph1_enc": "EAAQnb1kMr/e2/ADqo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

"EAAQnb1kMr/e2/ADqo" is the string i'm trying to match, however in the search results I can see multiple records with substring "/e2/" are also returned.
Looks like "/e2/" is indexed separately, so that this could happen.I thought the match query is to do full-text match... Is it because I missed something when creating the template? Any idea?

Add-on instead of reindex, how to modify the query to match the exact value in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which analyzer do you set in the mapping to index your data?

If you are using the default one (standard analyzer), then according to the documentation, this uses the [default tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) that seems to split also the text by slash ('/'). The documentation redirects [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Default_Word_Boundaries) for more information about the tokenizer.

So, that will index the following words 'EAAQnb1kMr', 'e2', and 'ADqo'. Accordingly, your query value will also been analyzed the same way the field was indexed. That is why documents with 'e2' are also being returned.

If you don't need to tokenize the 'ph1_enc' field, you can just set its type in the mapping as 'keyword'.

```
"properties": {
    "ph1_enc": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
 }
```

That will not analyze the field and it will match exactly while you query.

I hope that it helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying. this makes sense now, since the query is also analyzed. so the question comes to if I update the mapping, do I have to reindex the whole data?

Comment: Yes, you have to reindex the data. Check the [reindex api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) and the [index aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html) so you can make the process easier :)